# MatLab kinect detection

Tags: matlab, usb, kinect

I'm using the image acquisition toolbox to capture my video with the kinect.

When using `info = imaqhwinfo`, I get the current information :

```
info = 

InstalledAdaptors: {'gentl'  'gige'  'kinect'  'matrox'  'winvideo'}
    MATLABVersion: '8.1 (R2013a)'
      ToolboxName: 'Image Acquisition Toolbox'
   ToolboxVersion: '4.5 (R2013a)'
```

Where the kinect device is listed because I have installed the Kinect SDK ( Drivers ).

But If I disconnect the camera, Kinect still in the list because it's InstalledAdaptors and not Connected.

How can I know if the kinect if connected or not. Because you can create the videoinput with no problem and after that, you have problem to start it and I want to avoid this with a condition to detect connected device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I didn't waste my time on Instrument control toolbox to work with usb port and others.

I just surrend my code with a simple try catch and If I get `imaq:videoinput:noDevices` error, I just tell user kinect isn't connected and that it.